# Is there any way to implement multiple reference in servicenow?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

In service now for reference, there's a field type called '**reference**'. Now I need to create a multi-reference field. But I don't see any field type for it. Can we achieve the same using field type '**List**'? If yes, How to achieve it in the UI and REST API?
Multi-reference means **to search through multiple objects**

FYI, I'm using Madrid version and Customer Service Plugin.

Comment: I just realized, maybe you can solve this with dependent field: https://docs.servicenow.com/administer/field_administration/task/t_MakingAFieldDependent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as multiple table reference Field. How should the system react, if you write eg. Incidents and Catalog Items in the same Field?
I would advice you to just make two Fields, each with it's own reference table.

If you really want multiple types of references to pick, you would have to create a new table, import eg. Incident and Catalog Item references into that table and create a reference Field to that table.